# How to make Listview with normal transcript mode scrolls down smoothly?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-styles

I have a `ListView` for my Chat.
When new message comes I need to scroll that List down automatically. I did it using

```
chatView.setTranscriptMode(AbsListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_NORMAL);
```

Everything works like a charm, but I want list to scroll down smoothly, like with `smoothScrollBy()` method. Now it just jumps to the end when `notifyDataSetChanger()` is called.

How can I achieve that?
Here's My ListView xml item, just in case:

```
 <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:divider="@null" android:dividerHeight="4dp"
        android:id="@+id/chat" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/background_green"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/between_elements_spacing"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it a bit frustrating that transcript mode doesn't have an "animated" option. The way to accomplish this is to disable transcript mode, and after calling notifyDataSetChanged():

```
if (determineIfListViewShouldAutoScroll()) {
    mainThreadHandler.post(() -> {
        listView.setSelection(adapter.getCount() - 2);
    });
    mainThreadHandler.post(() -> {
        listView.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.getCount());
    });
}
```

Since you've disabled transcript mode, now you need to create a `determineIfListViewShouldAutoScroll()` function that determines whether or not to do anything. Use `chatListView.getLastVisiblePosition()` to determine whether the list view is scrolled far enough to merit automatically showing the new item. For something akin to transcript mode "normal" you would just check that the last visible item position is within 1 or 2 of the total item count.

This doesn't give you any control over the animation, list view is gonna do whatever it wants to do. If you *need* more control, you can run a custom animation that each tick calls `listView.setSelectionFromTop(lastItemPosition, listviewHeight - distanceY);` where listviewHeight is the height of the entire listview and distanceY is the animated value between 0 and the new view's measured height.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried using this

```
list.smoothScrollToPosition(postitionOfRow);
```

notifyData should not be scrolling anywhere if used correctly. can you post the code where you do that?

Comment: Wrong. With listview's transcript mode setted to "AbsListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_NORMAL" it will scroll it automatically.
From Android developers: " TRANSCRIPT_MODE_NORMAL: The list will automatically scroll to the bottom when a data set change notification is received and only if the last item is already visible on screen." ( http://goo.gl/IH9W0B )

And no, If I do what You say after each data set changed notification - it still now scrolling smooth because of transcript mode.

Comment: *it still NOT scrolling smooth, I meant.

Comment: Smooth scroll to position is only useful if the listview isn't already moving to the new item, which it will in transcript mode normal and always scroll.